# Word that means "to worsen esp. suddenly"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to look for a word(verb) that means *to worsen especially suddenly* to describe an injury/swelling.

I have chronic swelling in my lips and whenever I become too active, the swelling worsens and becomes painful and I'm trying to look for a verb to describe that without being too wordy. It's like similar to the word *attack*? but in verb form.

Comment: The swelling intensifies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A medical condition can be spoken of as deteriorating, or a person described as suffering a sudden relapse, but the worsening of a particular, non-life threatening condition such as you describe, could just be called a sudden flare-up of that condition.

Comment: +1 for flare-up, which can stand on its own without "sudden". http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/flare-up

Answer (score 2):

**[Angioedema](http://www.primehealthchannel.com/angioedema-definition-pictures-causes-symptoms-and-treatment.html)**

> Medical researchers define Angioedema as a condition that leads to rapid inflammation of the subcutaneous tissue, submucosal tissues, dermis and mucosa. It is also known by the name Quincke’s Edema and Welts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *inflammation/inflamed* if you want something different, although that doesn't necessarily convey rapidity.  For that, I would say *acute inflammation*, although really *acute swelling* would be fine as well.

Comment: I have chronic swelling so the swelling is always there and it worsens whet I'm active. So *my swelling inflames acutely when I become too active*?

Comment: You still have acute inflammation, but in that construction I might say *exacerbate* or *aggravate*.  So, "*I have acute swelling/inflammation when I run*" or "*I have chronic swelling that is aggravated/exacerbated by running.*"

Comment: It’s not clear to me from the question that there actually _is_ any inflammation here. Body parts can swell for other reasons than just inflammation.

Comment: Maybe not in the strictly medical sense of the term - although there is swelling and pain - but in colloquial usage, sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could say simply that it **swells up**,  or that it **puffs up** (or **out**), **bulges**, or even **balloons (out)**, depending on how severe the swelling gets.

Answer (score 0):

For pain, you could say:

> The pain crests.
>
> The pain climaxes.

But maybe these verbs do not go well with *swelling* as a subject.